# Zend Database does not produce value

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

Please help! Any idea why it is printing:

**Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [jobid] => 1 ) )** instead of its value?

```
    $this->dbo->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
    $userOffer = $this->dbo->select()
    ->from('offer', array('jobid'))
    ->where('userid'.' = ?', $userID);

    $userAccept = $this->dbo->select()
    ->from('acceptance', array('jobid'))
    ->where("userid".' = ?', $userID);

    $select = $this->dbo->select()
    ->union(array($userOffer, $userAccept))
    ->order("jobid");

    while ($row = $this->dbo->fetchAll($select)) { 
        print_r ($row);
        //return $row;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $row[0]->jobid;
```

Use that instead. You need to return the row index which is an object and then access the property `jobid`. This is how you would do that, so it returns the value of `1`.